# What happens when you add an integer value to an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

In many posts I have seen answers like

> std::sort(arr1, arr1 + size1);

I do not understand what is happening at `arr1 + size1` where an array is being added with an integer, is it concatenation, or is it adding `size1` to each element of the array? Neither of them seem like a logical thing required to sort an array. I tried printing the result but, it isn't possible to print arrays in C++. Could someone please explain what is going on here?

Comment: Take a look at what the expected arguments to `std::sort` are.

Comment: "it isn't possible to print arrays in C++" - nonsense.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I meant to say i cannot do `cout << arr1+size1;`

Answer (score 1):

It's pointer arithmetic. `arr1` is a pointer to the beginning of the array, and `arr1 + size1` points to just beyond the end of the array.

Comment: More explicitly, it's a pointer to the **first element** of the array. That's important because the type of the pointer is pointer-to-element, not pointer-to-array-of-elements. +1.

Answer (score 0):

It's adding the integer to the address of the array (the address of the first element). Yielding an address (if the arithmetic is correct) to an element in the array.